# flume: assign key for partition kafka sink

Tags: apache-kafka, key, flume-ng

I'm dealing with a issue but i can't find any answer to solve it, neither in the flume documentation.
I want to take the absolute path of the tailing file and save it.
After I ewant to pass it to kafka sink as a key in order to have all the event with the same path in the same partition.
I have read many article that say that it is possible but i cant find the configuration to assigne in order to make it works. Can someone give me  references or example on how to configure the agent?
I have the following agent configuration:

```
source
agent3a.sources.source3a.type = TAILDIR
agent3a.sources.source3a.filegroups= f1
agent3a.sources.source3a.filegroups.f1 = /path/local/data/source/
agent3a.sources.source3a.channels= channel3a
agent3a.sources.source3a.batchSize=1
agent3a.sources.source3a.fileHeader= True

Memory Channel
agent3a.channels.channel3a.type = memory
agent3a.channels.channel3a.transactionCapacity = 100
agent3a.channels.channel3a.capacity = 100

Sink
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.type= org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink 
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.bootstrap.servers =########hostname1#####:port, ########hostname2#####:port
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.topic= topic_test
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.producer.acks=1
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.channel= channel3a
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.FlumeBatchSize=1
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.useFlumeEventFormat = true
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.producer.batch.size=10
```

tnk at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to configure the agent in order to assign the key for partitionin in kafka topic using the absolute path of the files in the data source. 
In more detail, it is necessary to set the property 'fileHeaderKey=key". In this way, when the event is passed to kafka sink the header contains the pairs key =absolute/path/of /the/file and kafka can use it as the key in its message.

```
agent3a.sources= source3a 
agent3a.channels= channel3a
agent3a.sinkss= sink3a

source
agent3a.sources.source3a.type = TAILDIR
agent3a.sources.source3a.filegroups= f1
agent3a.sources.source3a.filegroups.f1 = /path/local/data/source/
agent3a.sources.source3a.channels= channel3a
agent3a.sources.source3a.batchSize=1
agent3a.sources.source3a.fileHeader= True
agent3a.sources.source3a.fileHeaderKey= key #####property to set the fileHeader the 
                                                  key for partitioning###

Memory Channel
agent3a.channels.channel3a.type = memory
agent3a.channels.channel3a.transactionCapacity = 100
agent3a.channels.channel3a.capacity = 100

Sink
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.type= org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink 
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.bootstrap.servers =########hostname1#####:port, ########hostname2#####:port
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.topic= topic_test
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.producer.acks=1
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.channel= channel3a
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.FlumeBatchSize=1
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.useFlumeEventFormat = true
agent3a.sinks.sink3a.kafka.producer.batch.size=10
```